# Why does TypeScript allow a class instance to be assigned to a variable of incompatible type?

Tags: typescript

Given the following code, why does the TypeScript compiler allow the assignment `const c1: I = new C();`? The function call `c1.z(args);` will throw an error because `args` does not have the `first` property. Shouldn't the compiler recognize that an instance of class `C` is not compatible with interface `I` because the `z` function on `C` takes an argument that requires the `first` property?

```
interface CArgs {
    first: number;
    second: number;
}

interface IArgs {
    second: number;
}

class C {
    z(args: CArgs) {
        args.first.toString();
    }
}

interface I {
    z(args: IArgs): void;
}

const args = {
    second: 2
};

const c1: I = new C();
c1.z(args);
```

Comment: [Why are function parameters bivariant?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix it, just use property as arrow function instead of method:

```js
interface CArgs {
  first: number;
  second: number;
}

interface IArgs {
  second: number;
}

class C {
  z(args: CArgs) {
    args.first.toString();
  }
}

interface I {
  z: (args: IArgs) => void; // fix is here
}

const args = {
  second: 2
};

const c1: I = new C();
c1.z(args);
```